# Non negative simple and double $\sin$ series

Tags: functions, fourier-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the series $\sum_n n a_n$ converges absolutely. Suppose also that the function
$$f(x)=\sum_n n a_n \sin nx$$ is non negative on the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Then is the function 
$$g(x,y)=\sum_n a_n \sin nx \sin ny $$ also non negative on $[0,\pi]\times [0,\pi]$?

Comment: The series $\sum_{n}na_n\sin(nx)$ is not positive for all $x\in [0,\pi]$.

Comment: @MarkViola You mean it can vanish? Always this translation issue of positive in French which is not positive in English!

Comment: @MarkViola I also noticed that you edited $[0,\pi]^2$.Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is the derivative of $F(x)=-\sum_n a_n \cos nx$. Therefore $F$ is non decreasing. As $F$ is periodical it is always vanishing. Hence the $a_n$ are all equal to $0$.